# How to save a hash or json string into a jsonb field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

I have a json string from my active admin from `"{\"en\":\"Lorem\"}"`

I want to save this in my `question.name` field, which is of postgres jsonb type.

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :name
end

# db/schema.rb
create_table "preset_questions", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.jsonb    "name",               default: {}
end
```

I've tried the following:

```
question.update(name:"{\"en\":\"Lorem\"}")
question.update(name:JSON.parse("{\"en\":\"Lorem\"}"))
```

Result for both:

```
question.name
=> nil
```

Comment: Let check any error in your console when doing this? 2 your commands should work fine!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it to work by removing `serialize :name`. Looks like rails already knows what to do given that the column type is `jsonb`

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# db/schema.rb
create_table "preset_questions", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.jsonb    "name",               default: {} 
end

question.update(name:"{\"en\":\"Lorem\"}")
question.update(name:JSON.parse("{\"en\":\"Lorem\"}"))
```

Both return

```
question.name
=> {"en"=>"lorem", "id"=>"ipsum"}
```

Comment: am Using Rails 5.1.4 and seems that saving a json string in a JSONB field will save it as string and not as a hash

Comment: from what I found this is the new behavior starting from v5.0.0 here is the source https://github.com/rails/rails/commit

Comment: @medBouzid
 I think that bug is already fixed in newest rails

Answer (score 1):

In Rails, you can specify in your ActiveRecord Model that it must serialize a column before saving it, and unserialize it after reading it. It makes you able to save any structure in a **string column** of your database.

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
   serialize :name
end
```

Then you can save your hash just like this :

```
question.update(name: {en: "Lorem"} }
```

Documentation : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Well, it's just that you must have a **string column in the database**, and that you must give the hash itself as an argument of update, not an already serialized verison of it.